# parallel ajax calls in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

this may have been asked many times but I couldn't find any satisfactory resolution. 
this is how my application flow looks like:

- Step 1 Login.aspx
- Step 2 Load Session which call an ajax call 'x'
- step 3 Load Dashboard.aspx calls 3 ajax calls a, b, c in parallel

These 3 steps share cookie

as per my knowledge I cannot add all these requests in 1 thread group as Jmeter would not execute ajax calls, so  I have to put it in different thread group something like this:

- setUpThreadGroup

  - Login
  - LoadSession
  - Dashboard
- ThreadGroup1

  - Ajax call x
- ThreadGroup2

  - Ajax call a
- ThreadGroup3

  - Ajax call b
- ThreadGroup4

  - Ajax call c

but now I can't control the sequence in which these call in different thread group would take place. Is there anyway I can achieve something like below:

- First -- Login
- Then --  LoadSession + PARALLEL call for Ajax call x
- Then --  Dashboard +PARALLEL call Ajax call a +PARALLEL call Ajax call b
  +PARALLEL call Ajax call c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to keep your existing test design you can consider using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) so `LoadSession` thread will wait for cookie from `Login`, etc.

However faster and easier solution would be going for [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) which is designed to mimic AJAX requests.

You can install both the plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: once I install it, can I run test on blazemeter cloud? so blazemeter cloud would already aware of this plugin while running test?

Comment: It is better to upload `jmeter-parallel-x.x.jar` file along with your test scenario  .jmx and BlazeMeter will pick it up. Check out [Uploading Files & Shared Folders](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420175-Uploading-Files-Shared-Folders) for more details.

Comment: thanks @Dmitri, is there any way to pass this jar file from Taurus command line. My Taurus yml script has blazemeter configuration and calls jmx.